# Why can’t I pass parameters between two states (with a parent-child relation) using $stateParams in Ionic v1.3.3?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework, router

1. Codes setting up the router (the two states have a parent-child relation):

```js
.state("tab.my-profile", {
  url: "/my/profile",
  views: {
    "tab-my": {
      templateUrl: "templates/tab-my-profile.html",
      controller: "MyProfileCtrl"
    }
  }
})
  .state("tab.my-profile-mobileinput", {
    url: "/my/profile/mobileinput",
    views: {
      "tab-my": {
        params: {"mobile": null}
        templateUrl: "templates/util-mobile-input.html",
        controller: "MobileInputCtrl",
      }
    }
  })
```

2. Codes in the controller of the parent state:

```js
.controller("MyProfileCtrl", function ($scope, $state) {
  $scope.goToMobileInput = function () {
    $state.go("tab.my-profile-mobileinput", {"mobile": "123456"})
  };
})
```

3. Codes in the controller of the child state:

```js
.controller("MobileInputCtrl", function ($scope, $stateParams) {
  alert($stateParams.mobile);  // undefined
})
```

I can jump to the child state. But in the child state’s controller, I can’t receive the parameter (got an “undefined”). I’ve been stuck in this problem for hours. Could anyone help me find a way out? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my apps, I set parameters on url.

```
            .state("tab.my-profile-mobileinput", {
                url: "/my/profile/mobileinput/:mobile",
                views: {
                    "tab-my": {
                        templateUrl: "templates/util-mobile-input.html",
                        controller: "MobileInputCtrl",
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: Thank you, Fabio! I know this is a common way to set parameters. But I did also learn that $state.go("stateName", {"paramName1": paramValue1}) can do this work too and can pass multiple parameters conveniently. And in my case, I need this way. So I still want to make out the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: It also works with $state.go("stateName", {'param1': paramValue1, 'param2': paramValue2}); and url: "/my/profile/mobileinput/:param1/:param2"